# Contact that relate to other contacts

Tags: contact

I'm looking to have two related list on a contact. I have a contact that may have other contact that are "trainers". the other list is a contact could be a "Student" for a contact. For example:

- Contact Bob has two contacts Tim and Jim as Trainers
- Contact Tim has two contact Bob and Steve as Students.

How would this be best done?

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand you correctly, what you need is a trainer - student type of relationship and you want a trainer to be able to teach more students as well as student to be trained by more trainers. You do that using a thing that is called a "junction object" in Salesforce terminology. A junction object is an object which has two master-detail relationships, in this case something like: Trainer__c (relationship to contact) and Student__c (relationship also contact). Whenever you want to create the trainer-student relationship you make an instance of this junction object. To get the fields from Student and trainer to show on the related lists, you can use cross object formula fields from both.

Comment: We even have a fancy new doc module for this. Check out the many-to-many relationships section.  https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/data_modeling/object_relationships

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with [Relationships for the Nonprofit Starter Pack](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GLGPEA4), a free app that is a component of the Nonprofit Starter Pack.

But you don't need to be a nonprofit org to use the app, and you don't need to use the other pieces of the Nonprofit Starter Pack. It's there because it meets a business need that a lot of nonprofits have, but lots of other orgs have used it.

Relationships has the notion of reciprocal relationships, which could create a Student relationship automatically when you create a Trainer. All the listings would be in a single related list, which is a little different than the requirement you outlined.